# Subir y desplegar una aplicacion shiny con un paquete de Bioconductor en shinyapps.io

Tags: r, shiny

Tengo un problema:
Puedo correr la siguiente app en mi computadora, pero me da error cuando trato de subirla a mi cuenta shinyapps.io
El problema parece ser que requiere de paquetes de Bioconductor:

```
library(shiny)
library(BiocManager); library(EBImage)

ui <- fluidPage(
sliderInput(inputId = "b", label = "breaks", min = 10, max = 30, value = 20, step = 1),
plotOutput(outputId = "plot")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
output$plot <- renderPlot({
hist(rnorm(300), col = sample(rainbow(30), 1), breaks = input$b, border = "white")
})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

El error que obtengo es el siguiente

---

> Preparing to deploy document...DONE Uploading bundle for document:
>   1823062...DONE Deploying bundle: 2820713 for document: 1823062 ... Waiting for task: 695183197   error: Parsing manifest
>
> ########################## Begin Task Log ################################
>   
>   ########################### End Task Log #################################  Error: Unhandled Exception: Child Task 695183198 failed: Error parsing manifest: Unable to determine
>
> package source for Bioconductor package BiocGenerics: Repository must
>   be specified Ejecucion interrumpida

---

Answer (score 2):

He visto en los [foros de RStudio](https://community.rstudio.com/t/http-599-time-out-error-while-deployapp-with-package-mzr/20644/2) que se debe indicar manualmente la versión de Bioconductor que se ha utilizado para obtener los paquetes. Por ejemplo:

```r
setRepositories(addURLs = c(BioC = "https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.8/bioc"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Yo tambien he visto eso en los foros. El problema es que no se donde poner esa linea. Si es que debo ejecutarla antes de tratar de subir la app a shinyapps.io o si debo ponerla en el encabezado de mi app. De todas formas he probado las dos vias y ninguna me funciona.
el paquete `BiocManager` tiene una funcion llamada `BiocManager::::repositories()` que devuelve las direcciones de los repositorios para la version instalada de Bioconductor.
Cuando ejecuto `setRepositories(ind = 1:9, addURLs = BiocManager::repositories())` ya sea antes de tratar de desplegar la app o poniendola como encabezado, me devuelve el siguiente error cuando trato de subirla a shinyapps.io:

> Error: inesperado '=' in "ckages/3.10/bioc', BioCann = 'https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.10/data/annotation', BioCexp = 'https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.10/data/experiment', CRANextra = 'https://www.stats.ox.ac."
>   Ejecuci�n interrumpida

Si en lugar de ejecutar la linea para incluir nuevas direcciones url sencillamente pongo la linea antes mencionada como encabezado de la app y trato de subirla, me da el mismo error del principio: o sea, que no encuentra el repositorio de Bioconductor.

Si alguien puede por favor tratar de subir la app a su cuenta shinyapps.io y lo logra, decirme exactamente como lo hizo

Answer (score 1):

Finalmente encontre una solucion en [Este foro de Rstudio](https://community.rstudio.com/t/shiny-app-fails-to-deploy-because-of-biocparallel-bioconductor-package/33619/). Y en efecto consiste en cambiar el repositorio a traves de la funcion `options()`.

Antes de tratar de desplegar (`deployApp`) la aplicacion en mi cuenta de **shinyapps.io**, en una sesion ejecute el siguiente codigo:

```
options(repos = c("CRAN" = "https://cran.rstudio.com/", "BioCsoft" = "https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.10/bioc", "BioCann" = "https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.10/data/annotation"))
```

Esto establece los repositorios a los que ***shinyapps.io*** entrara a buscar los paquetes de Bioconductor. Es importante ademas especificar correctamente la version de Bioconductor. Como se ve en el codigo yo aqui estoy usando la version `3.10`, pero la manera mas sencilla de saber la version de Bioconductor es ejecutando `BiocManager::version()`.

Ademas se debe tener en cuenta que cada vez que se inicia la sesion los cambios realizados en `options("repos")` son reseteados, por lo que si se desea subir otra app se debe ejecutar el codigo de arriba nuevamente. Espero que esto sea util a quienes intentan subir una aplicacion shiny que contiene un paquete de Bioconductor a shinyapps.io