# ¿Como desplegar una app R-shiny que depende del paquete highr en shinyapps.io?

Tags: r, rstudio, shiny

El error en el deploy es el siguiente.

```
Error: Unhandled Exception: Child Task 765743448 failed: Error building image: Error fetching highr (0.8.1) source. <CRANPackageSource repo='http://cran.rstudio.org'> unable to satisfy package: highr (0.8.1)
Ejecución interrumpida
```

Saludos. Gracias.

Comment: Esta pregunta ¿tiene alguna diferencia con respecto a esta otra que has hecho: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/331612/subir-y-desplegar-una-aplicacion-shiny-con-un-paquete-de-bioconductor-en-shinyap?

Comment: Es totalmente diferente

Comment: ¿Por que la anterior se trata de un paquete de bioconductor y esta de un paquete de cran? ¿Por que no puede tratarse del mismo problema?

Comment: Y por cierto, ¿no podrías aportar un [mcve], que podamos probar para ayudarte?

Comment: Has visto esto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/331612/subir-y-desplegar-una-aplicacion-shiny-con-un-paquete-de-bioconductor-en-shinyap?

Comment: Tienes razón en que es un error parecido. El anterior ya lo resolví (el problema con Bioconductor) Ahora el problema es que busca en CRAN un paquete que no es de CRAN, según leo es de Rforge, y también lo tengo añadido en el repo